# AWS Lambda environment variable is not updated when execute aws cloudformation deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to update AWS Lambda environment variable.
The function is defined in SAM. Environment variable refers Parameter.
Like this.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: mobile api template

Parameters:
  MyKey:
    Type: String

~~~~~

myFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
~~~~
Properties:
  Environment:
    Variables:
      MyKey: !Ref MyKey
```

Problem:
I make `MyKey` empty in AWS Web console. After that, I want to fix it so do re-deploy but MyKey is still empty.

What I do:
`aws cloudformation deploy  --parameter-overrides MyKey=ABC123`

What is wrong?

Comment: This is a known issue. If the lambda code does not change then the deploy is skipped.

Comment: @P.Str link to issue?

Comment: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4638 @RobertSzot